# Using "Point"-Datatype in Phinx-Migration (in CakePhp)

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phinx

I'm creating an API for POIs and use the POINT-Type to store the coordinates.

As my company uses CakePHP I have to write a migration-script with Phinx.

But I don't have any Idea how to *correctly* create a column with the POINT-Type.

Sure, I just could make an "ALTER TABLE ..." in a handwritten Query, but maybe there is a better way?

---

Versions:

- Cake: 3.4.7
- Phinx: 0.6.5
- MySQL: 5.7.18

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: Sry, I forgot; edit-added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use "point" as you would use any other datatype as the second parameter of addColumn().
It's just not documented yet.

---

Credits for this solution are going to @ndm; 
I just think it's worth putting this as answer instead as a comment.

> Looks like Phinx supports point types for quite some time now (the docs are not up to date)... try to use \Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface::PHINX_TYPE_POINT as the type

Answer (score 0):

[Phinx](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/index.html) Does not provide an adapter for `POINT` yet.

You should create your query manually.

See also [Unable to seed data with POINT datatype #999](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/issues/999)

Comment: I've already seen this question, but thought it is somewhat unrelated because its inserting data into an already existing database. ||| Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this point, but I attached the link just to complement.

Comment: @DennisRichter Looks like Phinx supports `point` types for quite some time now (the docs are not up to date)... try to use `\Phinx\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface::PHINX_TYPE_POINT` as the type.